# PHP multiple forms and Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I've put together a little script that works fine in general, it just needs a minor fix and some Ajax code. Basically, it appends a couple of forms to each output line. Submission works properly, 2 POSTS and 1 GET. But I'd like it to happen without a page refresh, ergo the Ajax code. I've tried messing around with some but the multiple variables are making it a nightmare. Here's the full code, first the main page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$lines = file('file.txt');

foreach ($lines as $line) {
$field = explode("|", $line);

$name = $field[0];
$id = $field[4];

echo $name . '<br>';?>

<form method="post" action="submit-here.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">

<select name="FORM1" size="3">

<option value="Value-1">Value-1</option>
<option value="Value-2">Value-2</option>
<option value="Value-3">Value-3</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<select name="FORM2" size="3">

<option value="Value-4">Value-4</option>
<option value="Value-5">Value-5</option>
<option value="Value-6">Value-6</option></select>

<br><br><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">

</form>

<?php
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

`file.txt` is just your usual DSV flat file i.e. `field1|field2|field3|field4\n`

Which brings me to the required minor fix I mentioned, namely the line break at the end of each row generates a pair of "phantom" forms after every legitimate form pair, add more line breaks and get more ghost code, I tried using preg_replace and if...else to filter them out but without success.

submit-here.php:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$FORM1 = $_POST["FORM1"];
$FORM2 = $_POST["FORM2"];


$write = $id . '|' . $FORM1 . '|' . $FORM2 . "\n";


$fn = "file2.txt";
$fh = fopen($fn, 'a');
fwrite($fh, $write);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Can you show what if statements and/or preg_replace calls you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Multiple Forms Part:

This works for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>    
<?php
$lines = file('test.txt');
$count=0;
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $field = explode("|", $line);
    if (count($field) > 2) {
        //only print the form if there is real data
        print_form($field, $count);
        $count++;
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>

<?php
function print_form($field, $num) {
  $name = $field[0];
  $id = $field[4];

  echo $name . '<br>';?>

  <form method="post" action="submit-here.php">

  <input type="hidden" id="id_<?=$num?>" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
  <select id="sel1_<?=$num?>" name="FORM1" size="3">

  <option value="Value-1">Value-1</option>
  <option value="Value-2">Value-2</option>
  <option value="Value-3">Value-3</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

  <select id="sel2_<?=$num?>" name="FORM2" size="3">

  <option value="Value-4">Value-4</option>
  <option value="Value-5">Value-5</option>
  <option value="Value-6">Value-6</option></select>

  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="submit" name="submit" onClick="submitForm(<?=$num?>);">

  </form>

<?php
}
```

#### AJAX Part

In your html head, add the following script block:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript"> 
<!--
function submitForm(num) {
    //issue AJAX request
    var data = "FORM1="+document.getElementById("sel1_"+num);
    data = data+"&FORM2="+docucument.getElementById("sel2_"+num);
    data = data+"&id="+document.getElementByID("id_"+num);
    var request = getXmlHttpObject();
    request.onreadystatechange = 
      function() { if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) 
                      alert("Form received."); };
    request.open("POST", "submit-here.php", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send(data);
}

function getXmlHttpObject()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return null;
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Sweet, that worked in getting rid of the ghost code for me too, thanks! Any idea how I can get Ajax working in there too? It's the multiple instances thing that's killing me, refreshing only the currently active submission.

Comment: I'd need to know a bit more about what you're trying to do...I don't see any AJAX code currently.

Comment: Pretty simple, actually, just need each submission to not be followed by the usual full page refresh, with perhaps a "Post Received" confirmation being returned from submit-here.php.

Comment: Ok, updated with example AJAX functionality. I had to modify a few things about the forms that the php is generating, so that there would be unique ids for the AJAX to reference, so make sure you include the changes to that code as well.

Comment: I updated the code and added the AJAX block as per your instructions, the full page refreshing is gone but now nothing is being passed to submit-here.php, I'm not sure if that's due to the new and old code conflicting so I've edited my original post to include the code for submit-here.php

Comment: I totally missed your comment. Sorry about that! The problem is going to be assigning unique IDs to the form elements and then properly accessing them. That's where the `id="sel1_<?=$num?>"` changes in the php/html come in. Basically, you need a predictable manner of figuring out which form elements go to the AJAX submission. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, didn't think you were coming back! Anyway, I figured it out myself but thanks for the effort. ;)